# Jenkins - Build loop

Tags: jenkins, build, infinite-loop

### Solutions

When configing the branchs to build remove the wildcard *:

`*/master` to be only `master`

---

#### This error only occours when a GIT SCM is related to the JOB.

Ex: I have a daily job to build an Android project.
First i thought that it was a cron problem, currently im using **50 10 * * ***, but i have tried **H 10 * * *** without any success. When the time comes, it always build the job (Failure or Success) and it queue another job.. and so on...

*Would last have run at Friday, May 22, 2015 10:01:58 AM BRT; would next run at Saturday, May 23, 2015 10:01:58 AM BRT.*

Even a build with parameter it queue a another job everytime.

So it stays in a build loop, forever..

---

**Config:**

- Jenkins ver. 1.614.
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-46-generic x86_64)
- GIT client plugin: 1.17.1
- GIT plugin: 2.3.5

---

**Console Output:**

```
Started by an SCM change
Building in workspace .../jobs/PROJECT_NAME/workspace
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://GIT_ADDRESS/ # timeout=10
Cleaning workspace
 > git rev-parse --verify HEAD # timeout=10
Resetting working tree
 > git reset --hard # timeout=10
 > git clean -fdx # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from ssh://GIT_ADDRESS/
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress ssh://GIT_ADDRESS/ +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Multiple candidate revisions
Scheduling another build to catch up with PROJECT_NAME
Checking out Revision e6d726c2d31cb0d7e6fad4362ee85e6fac1712c6 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f e6d726c2d31cb0d7e6fad4362ee85e6fac1712c6
 > git rev-list e6d726c2d31cb0d7e6fad4362ee85e6fac1712c6 # timeout=10
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[android] $ gradle clean build assemble
...
```

**Maybe the problem is this?**

```
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Multiple candidate revisions
Scheduling another build to catch up with PROJECT_NAME
```

---

**The build loop:**

[image: the build loop]

---

**Job Config:**

[image: Job config]

---

**Global Config:**

[image: Global config]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review the beginning of the console logs, for both the job that you manually started, and the job that gets queued next automatically.

In the beginning of the console log, it gives a reason for why the build was triggered, for example `09:46:05 Started by an SCM change` or `16:06:58 Started by user Slav`. Please add to the question the start of **both** console logs.

**Edit:**
Now that we know that Jenkins detects an SCM change trigger we can further *speculate* that what's causing this behaviour is an SCM post-commit hook of some sort, or another script activation sending a request to Jenkins.

Post-commit hooks should not work if SCM polling is not enabled, but nothing else makes sense, so let's investigate that avenue. Add `/pollingLog/` to the build URL of the build number that was triggered "by SCM change". There is a chance that nothing would be found, but if there is, but let's make sure.

Next, if possible, bind Jenkins to a different IP address and/or port. If there are "rogue" scripts that are triggering secondary builds, they won't be able to adapt to changed address.

**Edit 2:**
Looks like there is a bug in **[git client plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Client+Plugin)** itself, it was **fixed in version 1.6.2**. Please check the version of your git plugins.
Sources: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-10767 and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20286

Comment: The first message in the log is: "Started by an SCM change". The "problem" is: NO CHANGES were made, and there is no configs setted to build after a SCM change. o.O

Comment: And the downvote is for ...? @FelipeVasconcelos updated answer

Comment: I didn't downvote any of the answers, that's does not make sense, since all of you are just trying to help. The <b>/poolingLog/</b> is an empty page.

Comment: @FelipeVasconcelo I haven't seen it asked, and I assume you've tried it, but just to be sure: restart didn't help? Also, you said it happens with any job type? What if you make a brand new job, don't configure any SCM settings, just have a single build step "execute shell" and have there something like `echo hello` or just `set`. Will this new job also display this "looping trigger" behaviour?

Comment: @FelipeVasconcelos also, please check the version of your git-client plugin, there is a bug in versions earlier than 1.6.2

Comment: My GIT plugin is at 2.3.5.

Comment: GIT client plugin (Shared library plugin for other Git related Jenkins): 1.17.1 - GIT plugin (This plugin integrates GIT with Jenkins.): 2.3.5

Comment: @FelipeVasconcelos Well, that bug was related to having a wildcard in "branches to build" and it looks like you do too. They had a workaround: *Add the "Force polling using workspace" to the job configuration through the "Additional Behaviours" section of the git plugin configuration for the job*. See if this helps in your situation. If it does, you should comment on that ticket that it's not fully fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Above screen shot looks  fine but i am sure there must be some other configuration.

can you provide detail (rest of the) configuration too?

Comment: I added the full job config, maybe there are some "Global config"?

Comment: Its really weird. can not figure out any anomaly from screenshot.
Are you facing similar issue with all jobs or just one job?

Comment: It happens to all job, no matter the type. Even if i execute one with parameters, the first one executes with the variables that i had put when the others starts with the defaults values.

I added the global configs screenshot.

Comment: Does it happen for on demand builds or just with time trigger?

Comment: As we were searching for answers, we managed to found that it is a error with the GIT SCM related plugin of some sort, not managing to fixit yet. So, if i create a simple project with no SCM related config, it is running OK.

Comment: Try changing the version of git scm plugin, Try with older version of the plugin (if you are using latest one).

Answer (score 0):

Please give below code in Build periodically section  and try if that resolves the issue

```
H(0-50) 10 * * *
```

Comment: I tried, without any success.. the build starts, and immediately add another job every time.

Comment: yup , seems like i found the issue from the above screen shot you shared , try removing the option quiet period., Uncheck the Quiet Period check box

Comment: I had a global "Quiet period", setted too... Removed all (global and project specified), and not success... (it keeps in the loop)

Im trying now to restart jenkins machine, to see if its kinda related.

Comment: Quiet period is the amount of time your job will wait to trigger it's next build, now as shown in screen shot it is given as 5 seconds , so it is looping the build two time for one build. , any how please let me if restarting Jenkins resolved your issue.

Comment: No success after changing the Global and Job "Quiet Period" value and restarting jenkins. As i was searching about this feature, i found this: https://jenkins-ci.org/content/quiet-period-feature (It kinda explains what this "period" is for), i dont think this is the problem. :(

I added the global config screenshot.

Comment: "Quiet period" is the time Jenkins waits after detecting an SCM change before triggering the build. This is to "roll in together" individual commits made in quick succession. Nothing to do with "looping".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your repo doesn't have more than one branch that matches your Branch Specifier by using the full path to the branch: "refs/heads/master" instead of "*/master"